# Android 2.1: Grateful for crash analysis help: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad 

Tags: android, crash, bluetooth, logging

The output at this post's bottom is produced shortly after cancelling bluetooth discovery within my app.

Can you please help me identify what goes wrong?

I've attached an uncaught exception handler to my app which indicates no exceptions have been thrown, so this crash log is all I have to go on.

The most useful and human-readable lines seem to be:

```
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
11-10 11:36:55.883: E/WindowManager(1197): find target window =null,but mFocusedApp!=null!
```

However I can't discern much from these.

Here's the output, I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

```
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383): Crash log at 11-10 11:36:55
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383): Build fingerprint: 'ZTE/P729B/P729B/blade:2.1-update1/ERE27/201005:user/release-keys'
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383): pid: 19494, tid: 19494  >>> com.ndb.mindpad <<<
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383):  r0 00000000  r1 6fe1332d  r2 00000027  r3 00000000
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383):  r4 00000000  r5 deadbaad  r6 00002ee8  r7 40000000
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383):  r8 7e9428b0  r9 2c31ad0c  10 00000350  fp 2c31ad08
11-10 11:36:55.854: I/DEBUG(19383):  ip ffffffff  sp 7e942820  lr 6fe142ed  pc 6fe10c58  cpsr 40000030
11-10 11:36:55.883: D/KeyguardViewMediator(1197): isShowingAndNotHidden() mShowing=false    mHidden=false
11-10 11:36:55.883: D/PowerManagerService(1197): setTimeoutLocked now=260259191 nextState=3 when=260265191
11-10 11:36:55.883: E/WindowManager(1197): waitForLastKey: mFinished=true, mLastWin=null
11-10 11:36:55.883: D/PowerManagerService(1197): setTimeoutLocked now=260259192 nextState=3 when=260265192
11-10 11:36:55.883: D/KeyguardViewMediator(1197): isShowingAndNotHidden() mShowing=false    mHidden=false
11-10 11:36:55.883: D/KeyguardViewMediator(1197): isInputRestricted() mShowing=false    mNeedToReshowWhenReenabled=false    !mUpdateMonitor.isDeviceProvisioned()=false
11-10 11:36:55.883: I/WindowManager(1197): interceptKeyTi().hapticsEnabled = true
11-10 11:36:55.883: E/WindowManager(1197): find target window =null,but mFocusedApp!=null!
11-10 11:36:55.883: E/WindowManager(1197): Waiting for last key in null target=null mFinished=true mDisplayFrozen=false targetIsNew=true paused=false mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{30294e70 token=HistoryRecord{2ffa24c8 com.ndb.mindpad/.Preferences}} mCurrentFocus=null
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383):          #00  pc 00010c58  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383):          #01  pc 0000b38e  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383): code around pc:
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383): 6fe10c48 4e17d003 51a02001 4d164798 24002227 
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383): 6fe10c58 f7fb702a 2106ee6a ef1ef7fc 05592380 
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383): 6fe10c68 6091aa01 1c116054 94012006 eb0cf7fc 
11-10 11:36:55.893: I/DEBUG(19383): code around lr:
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383): 6fe142dc 220ce008 2b005eab 1c28d003 47889901 
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383): 6fe142ec 35544306 d5f43f01 2c006824 b003d1ee 
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383): 6fe142fc bdf01c30 00024b34 000000b4 1c0fb5f0 
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383): stack:
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427e0  00000015  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427e4  6fe1335d  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427e8  6fe3902c  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427ec  6fe38fd8  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427f0  00000000  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427f4  6fe142ed  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427f8  6fe3b9cc  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e9427fc  6fe1332d  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942800  00002bc4  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942804  6fe38e08  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942808  00000000  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94280c  00002ee8  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942810  40000000  /system/lib/libicudata.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942814  6fe135cb  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942818  df002777  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94281c  e3a070ad  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383): #00 7e942820  00149970  [heap]
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942824  00000000  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942828  6fe3bb84  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94282c  6fe0f3c0  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942830  6fe38e08  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942834  fffffbdf  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942838  6fe38e08  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94283c  6fe3b9cc  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942840  0000a000  [heap]
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942844  6fe0b393  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383): #01 7e942848  6fe38e08  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94284c  6fe0b393  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942850  00000000  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942854  000000c1  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942858  6d034dcd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94285c  0000be08  [heap]
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942860  7e94288c  [stack]
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942864  6fe1ed9b  /system/lib/libc.so
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942868  00002bc4  
11-10 11:36:55.903: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94286c  6fb05ead  /system/lib/libcutils.so
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942870  0037f1c8  [heap]
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942874  0037f1c8  [heap]
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942878  7e94288c  [stack]
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94287c  2d5ca964  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942880  2c31ad14  
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942884  6fb05eff  /system/lib/libcutils.so
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e942888  2d5ca964  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
11-10 11:36:55.913: I/DEBUG(19383):     7e94288c  0037f9f0  [heap]
11-10 11:36:56.003: E/ActivityThread(1443): enter process activity msg= 113
11-10 11:36:56.023: E/ActivityThread(1443): exit process activity msg= 113
11-10 11:36:56.623: I/ActivityManager(1197): Process com.ndb.mindpad (pid 19494) has died.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates a bug in the firmware.

If this is a modded ROM, contact the makers of the mod with this information.

If this is a standard ROM, if you can create a project that reproduces the error, post that and your error information to http://b.android.com, unless you see that there is already an outstanding issue for these symptoms.

Comment: Thank you very much. Meaning it's the particular phone model at fault, or the version of Android?

Comment: This happens on several phone models you see. I believe two are running Android 2.1 and one is running Android 2.3 . Any further info you can give would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KomodoDave: "Meaning it's the particular phone model at fault, or the version of Android?" -- how am I supposed to know? "Any further info you can give would be much appreciated" -- what "further info" are you expecting me to be able to provide to you?

Comment: You said "the firmware", to me that indicates it should be the phone itself rather than Android. I wanted to know the specificity of your answer.

Comment: @KomodoDave: The phone is mostly glass and plastic, with bits of silicon, copper, and other materials. The fact that you are seeing this on multiple phones does not really change my answer -- I don't know if all of those phones are running, say, CyanogenMod or not, since they are not my phones. If they all run the original firmware from the device manufacturer, then the problem is probably with stock Android, in which case follow the instructions in the last paragraph of my answer. If they all run the same modded ROM, start with the mod maintainers, in case they introduced a bug.