# Random phone reboot (tombstone added)

Tags: android, bluetooth, tombstone

I'm testing my app that make extensive use of Bluetooth antenna. Sometimes my phone reboots for no apparent reason. I've extracted the last tombostone I got from the phone.

Can you help me to understand the reason behind the reboot? I feel like is something wrong with the BT adapter.

Here is the top part of the tombstone, if you need more I'll add the rest.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9001/GT-I9001:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/XXKQN:user/release-keys'
pid: 357, tid: 2204, name: BluetoothAdapte  >>> system_server <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
    r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 40051b50  r3 00000000
    r4 00000000  r5 55fcea14  r6 40a88f7f  r7 00000000
    r8 000004ae  r9 55fceb1c  sl 401f56a3  fp 00000000
    ip 40a8cebc  sp 55fcea10  lr 40023e91  pc 4002060a  cpsr 600b0030
    d0  6163696c70706120  d1  697375206e6f6974
    d2  442065687420676e  d3  62696c207375422d
    d4  7373616c43000000  d5  0c00000000750100
    d6  0400000000005a02  d7  006e6f6349000000
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 64656c6961662022  d17 656c6966206e6920
    d18 0049535352000000  d19 040000ffd2006e01
    d20 00656d614e000000  d21 530000000a007301
    d22 5320676e75736d61  d23 0d00000000000033
    d24 3fede16b9c24a98f  d25 3fe55559ee5e69f9
    d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 0000000000000005  d29 0000000000000000
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 80000010
```

I think this part is relevant aswell :

```
05-15 11:45:05.943   357  2204 D BluetoothEventLoop: Property Changed: Discovering : true
05-15 11:45:08.095   357  2204 D BluetoothService: updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(84:51:81:74:29:D4)
05-15 11:45:08.095   357  2204 E BluetoothService: Error: Object Path is null
05-15 11:45:08.095   357  2204 E libdbus : arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect, assertion "path != NULL" failed in file external/dbus/dbus/dbus-message.c line 1198.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
05-15 11:45:08.105   357  2204 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 2204 (BluetoothAdapte)
```

So something wrong happens with libdbus but I have no idea how this could be triggered by my application.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't understand how to read tombstone file, but think can give you the pointers on what to look for in order to find out why the error is happening.

First: consider the fact that the power supplied to devices radio equipment (including bluetooth) fluctuates based on the strength on the signal and interference. 
Second: there are power states in which a certain wireless radio can be. For example when WIFI is on but not being actively used phone puts it to low power state which can take few seconds to get back to full power state, this is also true for Bluetooth radio. Process of changing this state has big impact on power drawn on the battery and can lead to restarts if there are flaws in it or some other part of the power circuit. Try keeping your bluethooth radio in active state by doing some small operation (like ping on WIFI network or similar) and see if the phone becomes hot while doing this.
Third: Most probable suspect for this is a hardware issue so test on other phones available or try testing while your phone is on power adapter (plugged to the power socket not usb since voltage change on USB can also lead to restarting the device)

Note: Consider changing the title of your question since it doesn't say what the problem is and is not actually a question.

Comment: I don't really think is an energy-related issue. Phones are plugged in during my tests and the BT adapter is always active and sending data at costant time intervals. I fear that the OS is doing something wrong with the BT transceiver. This issue occours randomly on all my phones.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are closing a Bluetooth socket in two different threads.

Here are some links i found useful:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10551

[Invalid heap address and fatal signal 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662446/invalid-heap-address-and-fatal-signal-11)

It can also be a bug in the firmware. Are you using a modded ROM?(see this link:
[Android 2.1: Grateful for crash analysis help: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242055/android-2-1-grateful-for-crash-analysis-help-signal-11-sigsegv-fault-addr-d)  )